# Android: Can't use getIntent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I can't use `getIntent()`..

What else do I need to use `getIntent()`, What I want to do, is retrieve data from the parent activity. and I have put some values,

Do I need to declare Intent?

```
getIntent.getExtras().getString("CallerClass");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("CallerClass");
```

You were missing a couple of parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You code should work, assuming you're calling it from an activity class.